# array_push in PHP seems to get into infinite loop

Tags: php, loops, array-push

I am new to PHP. I am trying to read MySQL with this PHP code.

```
....
$sql = "select * from GameMaster where UserId = '".$_POST["UserId"]."'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$rows = array();
$return = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    
    $rows['UserId'] = $row['UserId'];
    $rows['Nick'] = $row['Nick'];
    $rows['Items'] = $row['Items'];
    $rows['Skills'] = $row['Skills'];
    ...
    $rows['LastUpdate'] = $row['LastUpdate'];

    array_push($return, $rows);
}

header("Content-type:application/json");
echo json_encode($return);
```

Soon after runnning this code, it gets into infinite loop.
When I deleted the array_push line, it did not go into infinite loop.
So I guess that'd be the problem, but I can't find out why.

Is there something wrong with my code?
The MySQL database is in Amazon lightsail.

Please help me. Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: There's no way that can be an infinite loop. The loop is limited by the `while` condition, which has nothing to do with `array_push()`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to copy everything from `$row` to `$rows`? The array keys are the same, so you can just do `array_push($return, $row);`

Comment: I see. I will try that. Thanks :)

Comment: It's the same. Really weird. Without array_push, it is OK , but the result format is not what I want. What could possibly cause this?

Comment: @Barmar You are right! I found out there is an error in the next part. Silly me !!! Thanks for your time~~~~~!!!!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to fetch all rows from database, and get data array of specific fields

```
<?php 
$sql = "select * from GameMaster where UserId = '".$_POST["UserId"]."'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$filtered = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_all($result)) {
    $filtered[] = [
        'UserId'    => $row['UserId'],
        'Nick'    => $row['Nick'],
        'Items'    => $row['Items'],
        'Items'    => $row['Items'],
        'Skills'    => $row['Skills'],
        'Items'    => $row['Items'],
        'LastUpdate'    => $row['LastUpdate'],
    ];
}

header("Content-type:application/json");
echo json_encode($filtered);
```

Comment: Why filter the fields when copying to the array? Just change `SELECT *` to `SELECT UserId, Nick, ...`

Comment: correct. he can write the statements to grab which fields in the sql too.

Answer (score 0):

foreach record of your database information you are entering new data to rows array

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Logic of you application here

    array_push($return, $row);
}
```

this pushes fetched row into rows array

how ever if you are not modifying database fetched information. you can fetch information as associative array and simply store it in variable. there will be no need for loop and storing in new array

```
$sql = "select * from GameMaster where UserId = '".$_POST["UserId"]."'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

header("Content-type:application/json");
echo json_encode($rows);
```